# How to make a method generalized

Tags: java, generics

I have a requirement where the DAO will receive a request to fetch the data from a table where STATUS column is TECHERR. For this requirement, I have written code like -

```
public void loadTable() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyDTO> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyDTO.class);
    Root<MyDTO> dashBoard = criteriaQuery.from(MyDTO.class);

    ParameterExpression<String> p = criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(dashBoard).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(dashBoard.get("status"), p));

    TypedQuery<MyDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    query.setParameter(p, "TECHERR");

    List<MyDTO> MyDtoList = query.getResultList();
}
```

Now I have got a requirement that there will 5 similar tables on which I have to do the same thing.

One solution for this is that I create 5 methods similar to above for each table and give call to them.

But is there any other better way where I can re-use the above method for different DTOs. For example by using generics?

Note - Please do not care about method signature and other stuff like return type etc. because coding is in progress.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create an abstract class DTO, and all   MyDTO classes inherit from that. In the method instead of List <MyDTO> ,  List<T> and could parameterize the method        public <T extended DTO> T loadTable ()...

Comment: at least you can minimize the code to duplicate by reordereing the instructions so the the ones, which are almost type independen stick together and extrect them to a method with an generic return type: `public <T> T fetchFromDatabase(...)`

Comment: Thanks gaston and timothy for your quick response. I will try it.